# Feature Matching with Noise

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, ransac

I'm currently trying to match features within the same image. The images are vessels that have shifted, and have left an "imprint" in the tissue. The goal here, is to match the vessel to its imprint and receive keypoints similar to what [SuperGlue](https://github.com/magicleap/SuperGluePretrainedNetwork) provides.

However, my issue primarily exists in the low contrast and lack of clear edges of the imprints. It's very similar to a footprint in sand - because the area surrounding the imprint is of the same texture as the imprint itself, it is difficult to segment.

An album of the vessels and their selected imprints (highlighted manually in red) are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdi5Y.jpg). If you have any advice, I would greatly appreciate it - even if code is not provided!

Comment: is it physically possible to acquire a picture where that imprint is clear to see?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz No unfortunately. This is why it's a challenge, haha

Comment: that album, including plain source as well as highlighted features, is very useful to understanding the situation! thoughts and approaches anyway: these things behave like spatial echoes so you might find them by looking for shifted patches of the image itself... you should expect to find the identity (0 shift) as well. other acquisition: Optical Coherence Tomography.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I do have matching OCT and widefield (Optos) images. Do you think this would help?

Comment: I've looked at the additional (2D) images and they showed no ghost at all, compared to the fundus auto-fluorescence (FAF) image given above. a volumetric dataset *might* show the vessel's ghost but I'm only speculating.